# Dummy variables overpower important feature

Tags: regression

I'm trying to use linear regression to predict estimated queueing time given a dataset of queueing records. The records contain the day of week, hour of day, and number of customers ahead in line.

Clearly, the number of customers ahead in line is the most important variable, so we would expect that that variable will have the "biggest" coefficient in the linear regression.

I want to also include the other variables, but since they're categorical, I used dummy variables (so I have 7 for day of week: is_Monday, is_Tuesday,... is_Sunday). I feel, however, that the dummy variables are too many so they're "overpowering" the important variable.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: We need more detail. Waiting times are not independent if there are more than one observation a day, how was the observations taken? It might be better to use some glm for positive data, such as gamma glm? ...

Comment: First, you'd have 6 dummy variables for day of week.  But, more importantly, what do you mean by "overpowering"? The number of dummy variables isn't really relevant, as far as I can see.  If day made no differrence, all those coefficients would be close to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are misinterpreting your results. I see two issues. You are mistaking statistical significance for effect size, and misinterpreting the regression coefficients. There is no reason for the estimated coefficient of the "CustomersAhead" variable to be larger than the ones estimated for the dummies. In fact, i would *expect* it to be lower!

**Suppose you have the following regression:**

WaitingTime =  MondayDummy + TuesdayDummy + ... + 10amDummy + 11amDummy +...+ 
               CustomersAhead

**What the estimated coefficients are telling you:**

MondayDummy = Average waiting time on Mondays (same interpretation applies for the other day dummies)

10amDummy = Average waiting time at 10am (same interpretation applies for the other time dummies)

**and the most important variable to your question:**

CustomersAhead = the increase in waiting time if we increase the customers ahead in line by 1 person.

**Making sense of it**

From the above, it is easy to see why you should not expect the coefficient for the last variable to be higher than the other coefficients. Adding one more person to the line cannot add more than the average waiting time...it will add much less.

For example, the average waiting time on Mondays could be 35 minutes. But the difference between having *n* or *n+1* CustomersAhead of you could be an extra 2 minutes.

This does not mean that CustomersAhead does not have a "big importance" (as you put it in your question). This is in fact determined by the p-value. The coefficient is merely telling you the effect size of the addition of an extra person.

Finally:
As pointed out in the comments under your question, since you have count data (number of minutes or hour?) perhaps a GLM approach using a Poisson model would yield more appropriate results, but this is unrelated to your initial question.